# Random Forest trains but tree count is zero?

Tags: c#, opencv, machine-learning, emgucv

I'm using emguCV to use OpenCV machine learning algorithms. I can successfully train a RTree(i get success) but when i try to predict it gives me always -1. Then i tried to get the Variable Importance matrix and the tree count and the matrix comes as null (i specified the params to built it) and the tree count comes as 0.

Does anyone has any thoughts on what i'm doing wrong? PS, if i use a decision tree i can get predictions.

I have 6 variables and about 11000 samples.
Below are the parameters i use:

```
        MCvRTParams param = new MCvRTParams();
        param.maxDepth = 8;// max depth
        param.minSampleCount = 10;// min sample count
        param.regressionAccuracy = 0;// regression accuracy: N/A here
        param.useSurrogates = true; //compute surrogate split, no missing data
        param.maxCategories = 15;// max number of categories (use sub-optimal algorithm for larger numbers)
        param.cvFolds = 10;
        //param.use1seRule = true;
        param.truncatePrunedTree = true;
        //param.priors = priorsHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(); // the array of priors
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting regressionAccuracy to a non-zero number. regressionAccuracy stops splitting nodes, if the accuracy within a node is better than regressionAccuracy. If you set it to zero it will stop immediately at the root node.

Comment: i tried different values from 0 to 15 but still nothing. Im using an eample from opencv for letter recognition and i have adapted to my dataset. it can build trees but the tests give me all 100%, which is strange. http://opencv.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.3.1-0exp1/letter__recog_8cpp_source.html

Comment: this is the output of the program
The database aus.txt is loaded.
Training the classifier ...

Recognition rate: train = 100.0%, test = 100.0%
Number of trees: 100
var#    importance (in %):
0       -1.$
1       -1.$
2       -1.$
3       -1.$
4       -1.$
5       -1.$
Proximities between some samples corresponding to the letter 'T':
proximity(0,103) = 100.0%
proximity(0,106) = 100.0%
proximity(106,103) = 100.0%

C:\Users\pedro\Dropbox\0000000TESE\000_visual_studio\testes\MLShiit\Debug>